# Problem about distances of points in the Euclidean plane

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, coordinate-systems, pigeonhole-principle

Consider the sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ of points in the Euclidean plane, such that for each pair $P\in \mathcal{A}, Q\in \mathcal{B}$, we have $\overline{PQ}\leq 1$. Prove that either all points in $\mathcal{A}$ or all points in $\mathcal{B}$ fit into a disc of diameter $\sqrt{2}$.

How do we solve this problem? I tried to use Jung's theorem, which yields that if the maximum distance in $\mathcal{A}$ is less than or equal to $\sqrt{3/2}$, we are done. Also, I found that if the maximum distance is greater than or equal to $\sqrt{2}$, we are done as well. How do we deal with the cases if the maximum distance is in between?

Comment: Do a prove by contradiction.  Suppose $P,R\in A$ but $PR > \sqrt 2$ and $Q,S \in B$ but $QS > \sqrt 2$.  Now you have $PQ,PS,RQ,RS \le 1$.  Manipulation the triangle inequality to get a contradiction.

Comment: Having all pairs of points $P,R\in A$ have $PR\leq \sqrt 2$ does not not obviously (to me) imply that $A$ is included in a disk of diameter $\sqrt 2.$ For example, if $A$ is an equilateral triangle of side $\sqrt 2,$ it has this property but is not contained in a disk of diameter $\sqrt 2.$ @fleablood

Answer (score 0):

Spose $Q,S \in B$ and $QS > \sqrt 2$.  Assuming $A$ is not empty (if $A$ or $B$ are empty the conjecture is vacuously true) then we know $\sqrt 2 < QS \le 2$ as for any $P\in A$ we have $QS \le QP + PS \le 1+1=2$.

Now construct the midpoint $M$ of $QS$ and a disc of radius $\frac {\sqrt{2}}2$ or diameter of $\sqrt 2$ centered at $M$.

Let $P\in A$  so  $PS \le 1$ and $PQ \le 1$.

If $PS=PQ$ then $P$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $QS$ and $MP^2 + MQ^2 = PQ^2$.  $MQ >\frac {\sqrt 2}2$ so $MQ^2 > \frac 12$ and $PQ \le 1$ so $PQ^2 \le 1$ and $MP^2 < 1-\frac 12$ so $MP < \frac {\sqrt 2}2$. And $P$ is in the disc.

If $PS > PQ$ construct a line through $P$ parallel to the perpendicular bisector $\overline{QS}$ and have it intersect $\overline{QS}$ at $K$.

Consider the right triangles $\triangle SKP$ and $\triangle MKP$ so $MP^2= MK^2 + KP^2$ and $PS^2 = SK^2 + MK^2=(SM + MK)^2 + MK^2$.  If $MP > \frac {\sqrt 2}2$ and $SM >\frac {\sqrt 2}2$ we'd get a contradiction that $1 \ge PS^2 = KS^2 + KP^2 > SM^2 +MS^2 > \frac 12 + \frac 12 = 1$.  $MP < \frac {\sqrt 2}2$ and $P$ is in the disk.

Similar argument would show that  if $PS < PQ$ that $P$ is in the disk.

So if so if the points of $B$ are not within a disk of diameter of  $\sqrt 2$ then $A$ *is* within a disk of diameter $\sqrt 2$.  Similar argument would show if the points of $A$ are not within a disk of radius $2$ then the points of $B$ will be.

Comment: The assumption that the points of B do not lie within a disk of diameter $\sqrt{2}$ does not automatically imply that $QS>\sqrt{2}$.
For example, B could consist of an equilateral triangle with side length $\sqrt{3/2}+\epsilon$ so the circumcircle would still have diameter $>\sqrt{2}$, however we would not have any $Q,S\in B$ such that $QS>\sqrt{2}$. @fleablood